# Create rgbd_image from pointcloud in Open3d

Tags: python, open3d

I added some filtering and other preprocessing steps to my pipeline in Open3d.

However I end up with a Pointcloud, but i.e. o3d.pipelines.odometry.compute_rgbd_odometry() takes in rgbd_images.

How can I convert the pointclouds into rgbd images or if this isn't possible take a workaround to store the pointcloud as depth png and read it using o3d.io.read_image()

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's an Open3D PCD object, and it has "color" data - then you can export a color image as follows:

```
rgbd_from_point_cloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.Type.RGBDImage
```

http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html

The above site will give you more details, you should be able to find examples on the Open3D github on how to better use.